# Tableau - add row without making it a subset of previous row

Tags: tableau-api

I want to add rows to a Tableau text table without making the row a subset of the previous row. Using the example below, I want values for teams and status to display on separate rows rather than status appearing as a subset of team. I also want to add a team filter so that if I filter on team blue, values for green row are zero and status values update . Is this possible? I tried creating separate worksheets but keeping things aligned is problematic.

**Example Data:**

[image: Example Data]

**Desired text table:**

[image]

**What I don't want:**

[image]

Comment: My initial reaction is that what you want to do is counter-intuitive and isn't the right thing to do. There is a way to do what you want but it's counter to how people intuitively view data and is confusing. And what happens when your users want subtotals or grand totals? Doing it the way you show will not yield correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select both the fields(team, status) simultaneously then right click and go to `Transform` > `Pivot`.

Then 2 Dimensions will be created. Drag the `Pivot Field Values` on to Rows section
and `Year` on to Columns section and keep `Year` in Discrete format.

Then drag `Number of Records` on to value field section.

**Before Pivot:**
[image]

**After Pivot and final viz:** 
[image]

Comment: I don't have the Transform>Pivot option, but I was able to pivot by selecting the rows on the Data Source screen.